# How to detect if speech to text is available on android?

Tags: java, android, media, speech-recognition, microphone

I believe I have figured out how to detect if an android device has a microphone, like so:

```
Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        List<ResolveInfo> speechActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(speechIntent, 0);
        TextView micAvailView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mic_available_flag);
        if (speechActivities.size() != 0) { //we have a microphone

        }
        else { //we do not have a microphones

        }
```

However, how does one detect whether the android device has speech-to-text capability? Or should the above be used to detect that? If so, how does one detect if the device has a microphone?

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code you attached is indeed used to detect if audio recognition is available [1]:

```
// Check to see if a recognition activity is present
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
  new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
if (activities.size() != 0) {
  speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
} else {
  speakButton.setEnabled(false);
  speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
}
```

To test if a mic is present, just follow the code in [2] and the docs at [3], when calling prepare() you should get an IOException if the mic is not available:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
```

[1] http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html
[2] http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture
[3] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html

Comment: Do I really have to prepare a recording? I merely want to see if there is a microphone, I do not want to record at this stage at all. There is no getMicrophoneDevices() method or something? And to confirm, if audio recognition is available, that is equivalent to speech to text being available? Also, an IOException could have several reasons other than no mic being implemented in the device.

Comment: @Tom yes i meant speech-to-text for audio recognition here; note you are just asking the underlying system if an activity exists that can handle an ACTION-RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent, so that does not guarantee  a mic is available.

Comment: @Tom *edit:* looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607743/how-to-detect-if-a-microphone-is-present-in-android it seems that the recognition activity is returned only if a microphone is available (it probably has <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" /> or this is implied by RECORD_AUDIO permission)

Comment: @Guido, so in order to detect whether there is a microphone I have to prepare a recording? This looks like a lack of API to me...

Comment: Another issue with this approach is that I have no path to set as I do not want to save any recordings. Are you sure this is the only way?

Comment: I have added your approach to my answer in code, please comment on it. I will accept your answer, although I wish there would be a cleaner way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Nope i'm not sure it's the only way; it's the way i implemented myself because i didnt find any other way to accomplish that task. Id guess that while more pad-like devices come out, which could not have a mic, they will fix this issue implementing something like in *Camera* class. Because of a cellphone without a mic makes little sense, i think they intended <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" /> was enough at start.

Comment: @Guido Thanks. Do you happen to know how to detect an external microphone? A device can have three microphones: default one, front microphone and a headset (or otherwise external) microphone. In the docs I only found how to find the front microphone other than the default one.

Comment: @Tom no idea; but i found this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_MICROPHONE didnt try it but that *getSystemAvailableFeatures()* method looks interesting

Comment: @Guide Thanks. That allowed to me to add a getMicrophoneExists method (see my answer). However, this does not say whether the microphone is available for use (aka no other app is using it), right? So the getMicrophoneAvailable is untouched :(

Answer (score 1):

After reading guido's answer, this is what I came up with. It looks very hackish to me, wish there would be a better way. I will accept guido's answer, but if there's a better way, please do tell me.

```
package;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

public class MediaUtil {
    //returns whether a microphone exists
    public boolean getMicrophoneExists(Context context) {        
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
    }

    //returns whether the microphone is available
    public static boolean getMicrophoneAvailable(Context context) {
        MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "MediaUtil#micAvailTestFile").getAbsolutePath());
        boolean available = true;
        try { 
            recorder.prepare();
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            available = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        return available;
    }

    //returns whether text to speech is available
    public static boolean getTTSAvailable(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        List<ResolveInfo> speechActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(speechIntent, 0);
        if (speechActivities.size() != 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```