# How to know if Android Device Headphone Jack is Mic Capable

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to find out if the Headphone Jack of the Android Device is capable of a Mic being plugged in?

There is a timecode generator that I want which plugs in there but it obviously wont work if the mic isn't available.

Is there anyway I can code a test to figure out if that jack can have a mic?

Comment: I've never actually done any Android programming, but does the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607743/how-to-detect-if-a-microphone-is-present-in-android guide you in the right direction? It appears that the check would be based on querying if your specific intent is supported, rather than directly querying if the hardware capability is present. So perhaps look for some `Intent` that is similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Quite easy to determine if there is a line-in-mic or not , you just have to see if the system feature for `android.hardware.microphone` is available or not . That's it .

Comment: I think he's talking about having a mic in connector on the headephone jack (for use with an accessory), not if the phone has a hardware microphone.

Comment: Yes. although the tricky part is, I can't test right now whether a headset jack to the phone will be the same as the time code generator plugging into it. but irregardless, i wonder if there is a way to figure out if the headphone jack is mic-capable.